# VBA Error Messages interspersed with running as planned

Tags: vba, outlook, reminders

I have a Macro that works inconsistently and  it is unable to run without an error occuring at some stage. It works without any problem for days but then doesn't, seemingly without reason. I change nothing, do not do anything different and am curious as to the fickleness of VBA/macros only having been dealing with them for some weeks now. An error is generated in those instances that it doesn't run as expected.

> Error :*object doesn't support this property or method*

--despite the option of caption being generated on the insertion of .

```
Sub SnoozedReminders()

    Dim oReminder As Reminder
    Dim oReminders  As Outlook.Reminders
    Dim RemItems As String

    Set oReminders = Outlook.Reminders
    For Each oReminder In oReminders

    If (oReminder.OriginalReminderDate <> oReminder.NextReminderDate) 
    Then
    RemItems = RemItems & oReminder.Caption & vbCrLf & _
    "Original Reminder time: " & oReminder.OriginalReminderDate & vbCrLf 
    & _
    "Snoozed to: " & oReminder.NextReminderDate & vbCrLf _
    & vbCrLf
    End If
    Next oReminder

    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    oMail.Subject = "Generated on " & Now
    oMail.Body = RemItems
    oMail.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: "fickleness" typically indicates a wrong assumption made when writing your code, but it's difficult to say more without knowing exactly where your error occurs.

Comment: ^^ Check to see when it errors if the object it is erroring out on is null, that's the most likely scenario with that particular error message if it normally works.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are trying to set a type to the object:

```
Set oReminders = Outlook.Reminders
```

Instead, you need to use the following code which uses the Reminders property of the Outlook Application class:

```
Set oReminders = Application.Reminders
```

For example, the following code gets the `Reminders` collection and displays the captions of all reminders in the collection. If no current reminders are available, a message is displayed to the user.

```
Sub ViewReminderInfo() 
 'Lists reminder caption information 
 Dim objRem As Outlook.Reminder 
 Dim objRems As Outlook.Reminders 
 Dim strTitle As String 
 Dim strReport As String 
 
 Set objRems = Application.Reminders 
 strTitle = "Current Reminders:" 
 strReport = "" 
 'If there are reminders, display message 
 If Application.Reminders.Count <> 0 Then 
   For Each objRem In objRems 
     'Add information to string 
     strReport = strReport & objRem.Caption & vbCr 
   Next objRem 
   'Display report in dialog 
   MsgBox strTitle & vbCr & vbCr & strReport 
 Else 
   MsgBox "There are no reminders in the collection." 
 End If 
 
End Sub
```